# How do i redirect when version number is not included in url (Url Web Api Versioning)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

i have this route attribute in my api controller "[RoutePrefix("api/v5/test")]". I want to allow my api to be consumed without specifying the version no. If no version no is included in url, then server will redirect request to latest api version. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. /api/v1/products

   ```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "V1Api",
       routeTemplate: "api/v1/products",
       defaults: new { controller = V1_Products }
   );
   ```
2. /api/v2/products

   ```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "V2Api",
       routeTemplate: "api/v2/products",
       defaults: new { controller = V2_Products }
   );
   ```
3. /api/products

   ```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/products",
       defaults: new { controller = V2_Products }
   );
   ```

Comment: You can do this using routing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add multiple RoutePrefix's on a controller.

One possible solution is to add multiple routes for each method. You can use '~' to specify the absolute path and ignore the RoutePrefix for the controller.

Example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v5/test)]
public class TestV5Controller : ApiController
{
   [Route("{id}")]
   [Route("~/api/latest/test/{id}")]
   [HttpGet]
   public IHttpResult Get()
   {
      return Ok("Hello World");
   }
}
```